# Django: is it possible to use filter on annotated field?

Tags: sql, django

For example if I want to search by first and last names of user at the same time:

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
qs = User.objects.all().annotate(name=F('first_name') + ' ' + F('last_name'))
qs = qs.filter(name__icontains='foo bar')
```

Is this event possible in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) expression for that:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

User.objects.annotate(
    name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
).filter(
    name__icontains='foo bar'
)
```

Django will turn this into a query that looks like:

```
SELECT `auth_user`.*,
       CONCAT_WS('', `auth_user`.`first_name`, CONCAT_WS('',  , `auth_user`.`last_name`)) AS `name`
FROM `auth_user`
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', `auth_user`.`first_name`, CONCAT_WS('',  , `auth_user`.`last_name`)) LIKE %foo bar%
```